# gunicorn via mod_proxy is redirecting outside of the project's scope, despite ProxyPassReverse

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

I have a WSGI-app (a Django project) running under gunicorn on `127.0.0.1:18731` and I use Apache with mod_proxy to redirect requests from `http://example.com/my-project/*` to `http://127.0.0.1:18731/*`. Static files are stored outside of `/my-project/`. If the Django app does not need to redirect anything, this works just fine, but if it tries to redirect a request (e.g. to add a trailing slash to `http://example.com/my-project/foo`), it ends up removing `/my-project/` from the URL, leaving me with the invalid URL `http://example.com/foo/`.

My mod_proxy configuration is as follows:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /my-project/ http://127.0.0.1:18731/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /my-project/ http://127.0.0.1:18731/ retry=0
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyErrorOverride Off
```

I do not want to force Django to prefix `/my-project/` to all of its URLs, in the interest of portability. Apache should apparently be handling the prefix on its own with the `ProxyPassReverse` line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've decided to switch to nginx, having been unable to find a solution to Apache's ProxyPassReverse problem for days after asking multiple help sites. Not to mention the various other issues I've had with Apache over the last year. The problem can also be solved by creating a separate virtual host just for the proxied server, but I'm personally unsatisfied with this solution. That said, **I'd recommend trying [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836138/383793) first.** I haven't personally tested it but his reasoning is sound (albeit a few months too late for me).

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem to.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location "/my-project/">
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:18173/my-project/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:18173/my-project/
    RequestHeader set SCRIPT_NAME /my-project
    RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL ssl
    RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-SSL on
</Location>
```

To enable the WSGI app to construct an absolute url we need:

- `ProxyPreserveHost On`, so the `Host:` header gets passed and the app knows the Hostname the client sees us at.
- Add a `SCRIPT_NAME` header so the app knows where its root is.
- Set `X-FORWARDED-` headers as needed. I'm using ssl too, so I have to tell the app it should use the `https` scheme.

I use [`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) directives, because I do a lot more stuff on this vhost. But you can easily rewrite this by passing `path` arguments to the [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [`ProxyPassReverse`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directives.

NB: [`ProxyRequests`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests) should be **Off**, unless you want a  forward proxy too. If you're reading this you probably only want a reversed proxy.

Django specific note: `settings.LOGIN_URL` is used *as is*, so you'll need to prepend the `SCRIPT_NAME` to it yourself.

Comment: ProxyPreserveHost On finally fixed it for me! Gad, had so much nightmare trouble with this. Had to leave off SCRIPT_NAME and X-FORWARDED, though, it worked fine without them. But, I'm using flask instead of Django.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this? I added my-project to the url you are proxying too.

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /my-project/ http://127.0.0.1:18731/my-project/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /my-project/ http://127.0.0.1:18731/my-project/ retry=0
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyErrorOverride Off
```

I normally use nginx for this sort of thing, so I'm not sure if that will work or not.

**Update**: the above didn't work so trying something else.

Try something like this and see if that helps. It is setup a little different. It proxies everything except media which is served via an alias. This remove the need to have /my-project/ at all.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
UseCanonicalName On
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com/access.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.com/error.log
ServerSignature On

Alias /media/ /home/example/example.com/pysrc/project/media/

ProxyPass /media/ !
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:18731/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:18731/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyErrorOverride Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This does not work. Django is expecting requests to e.g. /foo/, not /my-project/foo/, so ProxyPass must be correct the way it is. Altering ProxyPassReverse has no effect on my end, which leads me to believe that it isn't being used at all.

Comment: Updated my answer with another option see if that helps.

Comment: Also notice that proxyrequests is missing which means it will default to off which is normally what you have for reverse proxies. Another setting to play with if it doesn't work is proxypreservehost.

Comment: Your other option would indeed work, but the website I'm working on has content other than the gunicorn/Django site in its root, so I need to be able to put the proxied server in its own space. I suppose I could just create a new host altogether for the project, but I still want to know why ProxyPassReverse is failing.

Comment: you could also setup a subdomain as well for another option.. Did you try changing the proxyrequests or proxyprservehost to other values to see if those are the problems?

Comment: I have indeed tried changing both of those values. And setting up another subdomain is what I meant by creating a new host. I'll probably go with that solution for now, and if anyone else tries to use my application underneath a subdirectory, it'll be their problem, not mine. :)

Comment: Have you tried using nginx as the reverse proxy instead of apache? That is what I use and it is light weight, fast and easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the original problem by setting the *ProxyPassReverse* config to the actual domain name:

```
ProxyPass /my-project/ http://127.0.0.1:18731/
ProxyPassReverse /my-project/ http://mydomain.com/
```

Hint: [Apache ProxyPassReverse values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618952/apache-proxypassreverse-values)