# Python 2.7 or 3.0 for LAMP

Tags: python, python-3.x, lamp, python-2.x

I'm going to be building web pages and web interfaces. So far I have been using LAMP stack with PHP. I want to shift to python. Which of the two Python versions (2.7 or 3.1) is better for this use?

Answer (score 2):

mod_wsgi didn't really work with 3.x until 3.2, so I'd stick with 2.7 for now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's going to depend on which framework you choose to employ - for instance django does not run on 3.x.

Beyond that, it depends on how wedded you are to *only* using apache. If you only want to use apache + modules, heed Ignacio's advice. If you can cope with using a secondary webserver, you can try this approach with gunicorn or uwsgi: [gunicorn via mod_proxy is redirecting outside of the project's scope, despite ProxyPassReverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418016/gunicorn-via-mod-proxy-is-redirecting-outside-of-the-projects-scope-despite-pr)

Comment: I think you mean that django does *not* run on python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

["Thoughts on python3"](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/12/7/thoughts-on-python3/) is a great article by the author of the Flask web framework Armin Ronacher. If you want to go deep in "Why not use Python 3 for web YET", this article will answer all questions. The bottomline is: for now stick with Python 2.