# Apache ProxyPassReverse values

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, jboss, proxy

our IT is trying to configure a new apache/jboss/apj setup.

When I browse to  http://domain.com/jboss/test.jsp
and System.out.println `request.getRequestURL()`

I get http://domain.com/test.jsp
(without jboss)

My app encounteres a lot of 404's because of this.

The IT department said Jboss has no concept of the /jboss/ part of the url because of the proxy.  Are they configuring things properly or do I need to change my code.  To me my code is not portable if I have to hard code url paths.

### Edit-

Here is what they told me:

```
<Location /jboss>
    ProxyPass balancer://cluster stickysession=JSESSIONID 
    ProxyPassReverse https://domain.com/jboss/
</Location>
```

This article supports my question
https://sosiouxme.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/fixing-apache-httpd-reverse-proxy-redirect-rewrites/

Edit2
On our old server in a my login framework servlet used by a few apps I had 
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?message=You have successfully logged off.");

to get things to work with the new proxy I have to recode as
response.sendRedirect("/jboss/AppName/login.jsp?message=You have successfully logged off.");

I lose portablity and reuseabilty with the latter syntax.

The error (in Apache, not jboss) for
`response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?message=You have successfully logged off.");`
`File does not exist: /WEB/wwwssl/AppNamelogin.jsp`
Note there is no "/" between my appname and login.jsp

The error (in Apache, not jboss) for
`response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp?message=You have successfully logged off.");`
`File does not exist: /WEB/wwwssl/login.jsp`
Note the AppName is missing

Comment: Can you ask them what they have the `ProxyPassReverse` entry setup as?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [article you mention](https://sosiouxme.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/fixing-apache-httpd-reverse-proxy-redirect-rewrites/) uses [`mod_proxy_html` (`ProxyHTMLURLMap ProxyHTMLURLMap / /ajp/nocluster/`)](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html), which will fix links to use the right path prefix. This is not part of the default `mod_proxy` modules provided with Apache Httpd.

Instead of putting these directives in a `<Location>` block, using a single line syntax might forward the path correctly:

```
ProxyPass /jboss balancer://cluster stickysession=JSESSIONID
```

Comment: thanks.  Work is blocking the article you ref. I believe our IT is using ajp.  I was thinking the sysntax could be ProxyPassReverse /jboss https://domain.com/jboss/  or even   ProxyPass balancer://cluster/jboss stickysession=JSESSIONID  I could have IT try your suggestion too.  
    I just didn't want to give IT too many things to try.

Comment: I think it's down, not necessarily blocked. To be honest, I'm not sure whether that would work.

Comment: IT just told me they were running two proxies, one with apache and one within Jboss to handle some legacy apps.  They removed the Jboss proxy and my apps work fine now.  I do not know what they set the final reverse proxy settings to.  Should I delete this question? Thanks for helping.